# BadMethodCallException occurs when localhost is served

Tags: laravel-5

How do I fix this error?

```
1/1
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method paginate does not exist.
```

My code:

```
$tickets = Ticket::all()->paginate(7);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be as:

```
$tickets = Ticket::paginate(7);
```

When you call `all()` it queries the DB and returns all the tickets and then you are calling the `paginate()` method on the  `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` which will through the error.

Check out the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all records from the database pertaining to the tickets in a single request

```
$tickets = Ticket::all();
```

And if you want paginated results then use

```
$tickets = Ticket::paginate(7);  //replace 7 with the number of records you want to retrieve in one set.
```

Comment: one more help  <?php echo $tickets->render(); ?> this line in my blade.php file but $tickets is shown undefined, my return statement in controller :- return view('admin-pages.admin_ticket', compact('tickets','ticketopen','ticketsa','messages'));

Comment: Please share your controller and blade view code. Can't help without seeing your code.

Comment: <?php echo $ticketsa->render(); ?>   <?php echo $tickets->render(); ?>, i have posted my controller code above @Donkarnash